# Is there a way to run Jasmine 2 tests with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, selenium-grid

I have a large suite of Jasmine unit tests that were developed to run on a Selenium Grid using the jasmine:ci rake task provided by the Jasmine 1.3 Ruby gem.  There was decent integration between Jasmine 1.3 and Selenium Webdriver and running tests on a remote node was as simple as passing some environment variables:

```
$ rake jasmine:ci SELENIUM_SERVER="http://hub.localdomain:4444/wd/hub" JASMINE_HOST="http://currenthost" JASMINE_BROWSER="chrome"
```

In Jasmine 2, this capability is gone, replaced by an integration with Phantomjs.  Unfortunately, I can't find any discussion of migration options for people who still need Webdriver support.

Is there a way to run Jasmine 2 tests using Selenium Webdriver?  Does anyone know of any existing projects or documentation focused on this integration?  My query to the Jasmine dev list has gone unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the jasmine team, it seemed to us that most people wanted to run their tests headless, so with 2.0 we made that the default. Running the tests in selenium also made the jasmine gem have a number of dependencies that potentially made it harder to install.

But we also see the value in running jasmine tests in multiple (real) browsers as well. To this end, we [extracted the selenium code](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine_selenium_runner), including saucelabs integration, to [it's own gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/jasmine_selenium_runner). Jasmine core actually uses this gem to runs it's own tests across multiple browsers.

Comment: Thanks!  It'd be great if there was some mention of this in the Jasmine 2 docs.